# Pass parameter to method binding

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

I have a very simple Ninject binding:

```
Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(x =>
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
                .UsingFile(CreateOrGetDataFile("somefile.db")).AdoNetBatchSize(128))
            .Mappings( 
                m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("Sauron.Core"))
                      .Conventions.Add(PrimaryKey.Name.Is(p => "Id"), ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id")))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }).InSingletonScope();
```

What I need is to replace **"somefile.db"** with an argument. Something similar to

```
kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>("somefile.db");
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide additional `IParameter`s when calling `Get<T>` so you can register your db name like this:

```
kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>(new Parameter("dbName", "somefile.db", false);
```

Then you can access the provided `Parameters` collection through the `IContext` (the sysntax is little verbose):

```
kernel.Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(x =>
{
    var parameter = x.Parameters.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "dbName");
    var dbName = "someDefault.db";
    if (parameter != null)
    {
        dbName = (string) parameter.GetValue(x, x.Request.Target);
    }
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
            .UsingFile(CreateOrGetDataFile(dbName)))
            //...
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}).InSingletonScope();
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that this is NinjectModule, we can use NinjectModule.Kernel property:

```
Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(x =>
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
                .UsingFile(CreateOrGetDataFile(Kernel.Get("somefile.db"))).AdoNetBatchSize(128))
            .Mappings( 
                m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("Sauron.Core"))
                      .Conventions.Add(PrimaryKey.Name.Is(p => "Id"), ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id")))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }).InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: NinjectModule has a public Kernel property you can use.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I think I don't really understand what you mean. How would Kernel.Get("something") would help me achieve what I want. Could you please give me a snippet how to create ISessionFactory snippet passing "somefile.db" as a parameter?